# Equilibrium Distribution of Reducible Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

Let's say a Markov chain has the state-space $S = \{A,B,C,D\}$ Transition Matrix as follows:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
 0     & 0     & 0 & 1 \\
 1     & 0     & 0  & 0  \\
 0     & 0    & 0  & 1 \\
 0     & 1     & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is NOT irreducible as far as I am aware due to state C being transient.

To find an equilibrium distribution for the chain, would I just treat it the same way as if it were irreducible in which case I get $\pi = (1/3)(1,1,0,1)$. Is this unique? I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This Markov chain is [periodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity), so no stationary distribution exists. If we start in state A we see the pattern ADBADBADB... so we know every third time step we will be in either A, D or B. And if we start the chain in state C then the pattern is CADBADBADB...